# How to get to the admin page in Drupal

Tags: drupal-6, themes

I've downloaded Drupal 6 and installed it on my local server, and ported a basic web site as a custom theme. I've set this as the default theme and everything works okay; the page appears nice with all the images and layout.

The problem is that now, no matter what I type as the URL I always get to my page. So how can I go to the admin page? `/q=user` does not work. I can change the theme from the database but that is not what I want. I just want to keep this theme and be able to access all the Drupal functionality.

For the custom page i've created the `page.tpl.php` and `.info` file. Along with the CSS file I've put them all in a new folder in the themes directory.

Comment: @Mark - the only page that the custom theme has, that i've ported from plain html

Comment: How did you create a theme from the 1 page website? Did you put it into page.tpl.php? In that case, Drupal will always render whatever is there in page.tpl.php. In absence of more information, this is my guess. Can you provide some more information?

Comment: @abhaga - that's correct, i have only one page as page.tpl.php

Comment: Have you got the solution? Same here. I just installed. I can't go admin using url like http://pro.com/admin/. But I can login via user login form. I want to go through specific admin url. How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! Basically page.tpl.php specifies the over all structure of site. Look at the original page.tpl.php file - it will be printing a variable called $content somewhere. That is the variable holding all the content of your specific page. You will need to print it at appropriate place in your pge.tpl.php

You should check out the right way of creating a theme here: http://drupal.org/theme-guide/6

Answer (score 3):

@abhaga's answer is spot on - you've turned the entire site's theme into a single page's HTML, so they're all going to be the same.

If you'd like to avoid glitching the admin side of things with a bad template file, you can set one of the core themes as your "administration theme" (in Site Configuration) - that way, the admin backend will always use that theme regardless of the other templates.